# Problems with ReactJS and ExtJS3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, extjs3

I have page with ExtJS3 and ReactJS.

In order for the React to work in IE11 i use @babel/polifyll

In turn, Babel uses core-js which has this method:

```js
      "use strict";

      var LIBRARY = __webpack_require__(/*! ./_library */ "./node_modules/core-js/library/modules/_library.js");
      var $export = __webpack_require__(/*! ./_export */ "./node_modules/core-js/library/modules/_export.js");
      var redefine = __webpack_require__(/*! ./_redefine */ "./node_modules/core-js/library/modules/_redefine.js");
      var hide = __webpack_require__(/*! ./_hide */ "./node_modules/core-js/library/modules/_hide.js");
      var Iterators = __webpack_require__(/*! ./_iterators */ "./node_modules/core-js/library/modules/_iterators.js");
      var $iterCreate = __webpack_require__(/*! ./_iter-create */ "./node_modules/core-js/library/modules/_iter-create.js");
      var setToStringTag = __webpack_require__(/*! ./_set-to-string-tag */ "./node_modules/core-js/library/modules/_set-to-string-tag.js");
      var getPrototypeOf = __webpack_require__(/*! ./_object-gpo */ "./node_modules/core-js/library/modules/_object-gpo.js");
      var ITERATOR = __webpack_require__(/*! ./_wks */ "./node_modules/core-js/library/modules/_wks.js")('iterator');
      var BUGGY = !([].keys && 'next' in [].keys()); // Safari has buggy iterators w/o `next`
      var FF_ITERATOR = '@@iterator';
      var KEYS = 'keys';
      var VALUES = 'values';

      module.exports = function (Base, NAME, Constructor, next, DEFAULT, IS_SET, FORCED) {
        $iterCreate(Constructor, NAME, next);
        var getMethod = function (kind) {
          if (!BUGGY && kind in proto) return proto[kind];
          switch (kind) {
            case KEYS: return function keys() { return new Constructor(this, kind); };
            case VALUES: return function values() { return new Constructor(this, kind); }; //AT THIS POINT
          } return function entries() { return new Constructor(this, kind); };
        }
        //SOME PARTS OF THIS METHOD
      };
```

in **case VALUES: return function values() { return new Constructor(this, kind); };** i have something which make something and this part of code broke ExtJS3 methods like this:

```js
Ext.XTemplate = function(){
    Ext.XTemplate.superclass.constructor.apply(this, arguments);

    var me = this,
     s = me.html,
     re = /<tpl\b[^>]*>((?:(?=([^<]+))\2|<(?!tpl\b[^>]*>))*?)<\/tpl>/,
     nameRe = /^<tpl\b[^>]*?for="(.*?)"/,
     ifRe = /^<tpl\b[^>]*?if="(.*?)"/,
     execRe = /^<tpl\b[^>]*?exec="(.*?)"/,
     m,
     id = 0,
     tpls = [],
     VALUES = 'values',
     PARENT = 'parent',
     XINDEX = 'xindex',
     XCOUNT = 'xcount',
     RETURN = 'return ',
     WITHVALUES = 'with(values){ ';

    s = ['<tpl>', s, '</tpl>'].join('');

    while((m = s.match(re))){
        var m2 = m[0].match(nameRe),
   m3 = m[0].match(ifRe),
         m4 = m[0].match(execRe),
         exp = null,
         fn = null,
         exec = null,
         name = m2 && m2[1] ? m2[1] : '';

       if (m3) {
           exp = m3 && m3[1] ? m3[1] : null;
           if(exp){
               fn = new Function(VALUES, PARENT, XINDEX, XCOUNT, WITHVALUES + RETURN +(Ext.util.Format.htmlDecode(exp))+'; }');
           }
       }
       if (m4) {
           exp = m4 && m4[1] ? m4[1] : null;
           if(exp){
               exec = new Function(VALUES, PARENT, XINDEX, XCOUNT, WITHVALUES +(Ext.util.Format.htmlDecode(exp))+'; }');
           }
       }
       if(name){
           switch(name){
               case '.': name = new Function(VALUES, PARENT, WITHVALUES + RETURN + VALUES + '; }'); break;
               case '..': name = new Function(VALUES, PARENT, WITHVALUES + RETURN + PARENT + '; }'); break;
               default: name = new Function(VALUES, PARENT, WITHVALUES + RETURN + name + '; }');
           }
       }
       tpls.push({
            id: id,
            target: name,
            exec: exec,
            test: fn,
            body: m[1]||''
        });
       s = s.replace(m[0], '{xtpl'+ id + '}');
       ++id;
    }
 Ext.each(tpls, function(t) {
        me.compileTpl(t);
    });
    me.master = tpls[tpls.length-1];
    me.tpls = tpls;
};
Ext.extend(Ext.XTemplate, Ext.Template, {
    // private
    re : /\{([\w-\.\#]+)(?:\:([\w\.]*)(?:\((.*?)?\))?)?(\s?[\+\-\*\\]\s?[\d\.\+\-\*\\\(\)]+)?\}/g,
    // private
    codeRe : /\{\[((?:\\\]|.|\n)*?)\]\}/g,

    // private
    applySubTemplate : function(id, values, parent, xindex, xcount){
        var me = this,
         len,
         t = me.tpls[id],
         vs,
         buf = [];
        if ((t.test && !t.test.call(me, values, parent, xindex, xcount)) ||
            (t.exec && t.exec.call(me, values, parent, xindex, xcount))) {
            return '';
        }
        vs = t.target ? t.target.call(me, values, parent) : values;
        len = vs.length;
        parent = t.target ? values : parent;
        if(t.target && Ext.isArray(vs)){
         Ext.each(vs, function(v, i) {
                buf[buf.length] = t.compiled.call(me, v, parent, i+1, len);
            });
            return buf.join('');
        }
        return t.compiled.call(me, vs, parent, xindex, xcount);
    },

    // private
    compileTpl : function(tpl){
        var fm = Ext.util.Format,
         useF = this.disableFormats !== true,
            sep = Ext.isGecko ? "+" : ",",
            body;

        function fn(m, name, format, args, math){
            if(name.substr(0, 4) == 'xtpl'){
                return "'"+ sep +'this.applySubTemplate('+name.substr(4)+', values, parent, xindex, xcount)'+sep+"'";
            }
            var v;
            if(name === '.'){
                v = 'values';
            }else if(name === '#'){
                v = 'xindex';
            }else if(name.indexOf('.') != -1){
                v = name;
            }else{
                v = "values['" + name + "']";
            }
            if(math){
                v = '(' + v + math + ')';
            }
            if (format && useF) {
                args = args ? ',' + args : "";
                if(format.substr(0, 5) != "this."){
                    format = "fm." + format + '(';
                }else{
                    format = 'this.call("'+ format.substr(5) + '", ';
                    args = ", values";
                }
            } else {
                args= ''; format = "("+v+" === undefined ? '' : ";
            }
            return "'"+ sep + format + v + args + ")"+sep+"'";
        }

        function codeFn(m, code){
            return "'"+ sep +'('+code+')'+sep+"'";
        }

        // branched to use + in gecko and [].join() in others
        if(Ext.isGecko){
            body = "tpl.compiled = function(values, parent, xindex, xcount){ return '" +
                   tpl.body.replace(/(\r\n|\n)/g, '\\n').replace(/'/g, "\\'").replace(this.re, fn).replace(this.codeRe, codeFn) +
                    "';};";
        }else{
            body = ["tpl.compiled = function(values, parent, xindex, xcount){ return ['"];
            body.push(tpl.body.replace(/(\r\n|\n)/g, '\\n').replace(/'/g, "\\'").replace(this.re, fn).replace(this.codeRe, codeFn));
            body.push("'].join('');};");
            body = body.join('');
        }
        eval(body);
        return this;
    },

    applyTemplate : function(values){
        return this.master.compiled.call(this, values, {}, 1, 1);
    },

    compile : function(){return this;}


});

Ext.XTemplate.prototype.apply = Ext.XTemplate.prototype.applyTemplate;

Ext.XTemplate.from = function(el){
    el = Ext.getDom(el);
    return new Ext.XTemplate(el.value || el.innerHTML);
};/*!
```

On line 92 in **vs** variable i have this method **function values() { return new Constructor(this, kind); };** from core-js.

I don't know what i need to do, because we need a several months (maybe year) to stay with ExtJS3 but many things in ExtJS3 not work.

**EDIT**
Also no one have access to ExtJS3 for make software crutch

Comment: Experiencing the same issue. I'm looking into why it breaks, hopefully with a solution ...

Comment: @r3dst0rm See answer bellow. Should help

Answer (score 1):

Hard fix:

just create `fix.sh` file, put it in a root of project along with webpack config and put this source to `fix.sh`:

```
sed -i 's/getMethod/_getMethod/g' target/application/static/js/*.js && sed -i 's/KEYS/_KEYS/g' target/application/static/js/*.js &&
sed -i 's/VALUES/_VALUES/g' target/application/static/js/*.js &&
sed -i 's/keys/_keys/g' target/application/static/js/*.js &&
sed -i 's/values/_values/g' target/application/static/js/*.js
```

also replace `target/application/static/js` path to yours.

Add `WebpackShellPlugin` and in webpack add this:

```
plugins: [
    new WebpackShellPlugin({  
         onBuildEnd: ['bash ./fix.sh'] 
    })
]
```